# Can't pass id to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

Have have this in my view

```
@Html.ActionLink("Lock", "Locked", new { id = item.Id })
```

I also tested with

```
@Html.ActionLink("Lock", "Locked", new { id = item.Id }, FormMethod.Post)
```

And this in my controller

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Locked")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Locked(string userId)
{
    var locked = UserManager.IsLockedOutAsync(userId);
    if (false)
    {
        UserManager.SetLockoutEnabled(userId, true);
    }
    else
    {
        UserManager.SetLockoutEnabled(userId, false);
    }
    return View();
}
```

I have an Id in my view/link if I hover the link lock. But if I debug my application in the controller the string userId is "Null".

My goal is to send the userId to the controller. Find if the user is locked in the database. If the user is locked, unlock the user. If the user is not locked then I should lock the user. Lock is true and false in the database and I use asp.net Identity and the column LockoutEnabled

Comment: What does your route look like?

Comment: Your parameter is named `userId` so its `new { userId = item.Id }`

Comment: Make sure you have `@Html.BeginForm()` on your view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are posting the parameter `id` when your Action method is expecting the parameter of `userId`. So it will result in a `null` as there is no matching parameter on the Action methods signature.

Use this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Lock", "Locked", new { userId = item.Id })
```